# Spring AutoWire not working when invoking CRUD Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I am having a spring boot app which connects to database using Spring JPA and retreives the data for processing. When I try to autowire using I am getting below error. Can someone please throw somelight.

I have added application entry point , Repo and Tasklet below. Please check it.

**Application Entry Point**

```
package com.printbatch;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.printbatch.config")
public class AgencyBillPayFileUploadApplication implements 
CommandLineRunner{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AgencyBillPayFileUploadApplication.class, args);
}

   //access command line arguments




@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("args");
    System.out.println(args[0]);


    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "ABPBatchInfrastructure.xml",
            "AgencyBillPayFileUploadApp.xml"
    );

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job = ctx.getBean(Job.class);       

    /*
     * jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addString("inputResource",
     * "file:./products.zip") .addString("targetDirectory",
     * "./importproductsbatch/").addString("targetFile", "products.txt")
     * .addString("date", "2020-06-02").toJobParameters());
     */

    jobLauncher.run(job,
            new JobParametersBuilder().addString("inputResource", "file:./products.zip")
                    .addString("targetDirectory", "./importproductsbatch/").addString("targetFile", "products.txt")
                    .addString("date", "2005-07-29").toJobParameters());



}
```

}

```
package com.printbatch.config;

    @Component
    public interface PrintJobItemRepo extends CrudRepository<PrintJobItem, Integer> {

    List<PrintJobItem> findByPrintStatusEquals(String printStatus );

    }
```

Calling this component in this class

```
package com.printbatch.tasklet;
public class ReadInputFile implements Tasklet {

    private Resource inputResource;
    private String   targetDirectory;


    @Autowired
    private PrintJobItemRepo pjr;

}
```

Error below

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.decompressTasklet': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'pjr'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'com.printbatch.repo.PrintJobItemRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as 
autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Can you also add the packages structure?

Comment: Also try to add the `@Component` to ReadInputFile

Answer (score 2):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'com.printbatch.repo.PrintJobItemRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as 
autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
```

Stack trace tells pretty well what is going on. **com.printbatch.repo.PrintJobItemRepo**

You are trying to autowire a class that is not in the JPA repository path. Move your class into **com.printbatch.config** package.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @Component from PrintJobItemRepo. Is ReadInputFile a managed bean? If not, you should annotate it with Component, Service, or make it as a Bean, so it must become managed object. Spring can only inject managed bean into another managed bean.

Comment: Hi @Zlaval , @ Ehab Kadhah , @ the alchemist
Thanks for all your suggestions. I have updated question with Package structure and Main Spring boot Class file . Please check it. Also I tried removing component annotation from Repo and added in ReadInputFile Tasklet. It still shows the same error. Just for your FYI, this is a spring batch application in spring boot. I have written Spring boot Rest API before , I didnt annotate repo with any annotation in that project but still it worked when I autowired it without issues. Not sure why its not working in this case. Please help me.

Comment: Hi @ Eric @ Zlaval @ Ehab . Thanks for all your suggestions. Moving the JPA to config package did the trick . Now it is working as expected. Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 0):

Add @Component to ReadInputFile class.
Remove @Component from PrintJobItemRepo class.
We generally use @Repository annotation over such classes.
Check out some examples to see how this works -

[Spring boot crud example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-crud-hibernate/)
[Another Spring boot crud example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/boot/spring-boot-crud-operations-example/)

Comment: Hi @Zlaval , @ Ehab Kadhah , @ the alchemist Thanks for all your suggestions. I have updated question with Package structure and Main Spring boot Class file . Please check it. Also I tried removing component annotation from Repo and added in ReadInputFile Tasklet. It still shows the same error. Just for your FYI, this is a spring batch application in spring boot. I have written Spring boot Rest API before , I didnt annotate repo with any annotation in that project but still it worked when I autowired it without issues. Not sure why its not working in this case. Please help me.